# How do I document functions inside of a return?

Tags: jsdoc

How do I document functions inside of a return? In this example, I need then() documented. I have tried adding @memberOf and @name to get it to generate. Nothing seems to work for me.

```
/**
 * The description for the outer function 
 * @param {string} test Example argument
 * @return {Object}
 */
example.func = function(test) {
   return {
       /**
        * The description for the inner "then" function
        * @param {Function} cb The callback function
        */
       then: function(cb) { }
   }
}
```

**Update** Added JSDoc comments to the top to prevent confusion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSDoc: Return object structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763257/jsdoc-return-object-structure)

Answer (score 1):

`JSDoc comments` must be above the declaration, the [`return`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-returns.html) statement must be declared with `@returns {type} value` (note that `@return` is a synonyms)

```js
/**
 * Returns the sum of a and b
 *
 * @param {Number} a
 * @param {Number} [b = 0]
 * @returns {Number}
 */
function sum(a, b = 0) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to document a function inside a return - like a promise.  The outside function had its own jsdoc comment but didn't include it inside de the example to make it concise.

Comment: If you are returning a Promise, you must do: `@returns {Promise}`.

Comment: It's not a promise. I said like a promise. See the above code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763257/jsdoc-return-object-structure