# how to specify returned object format in javascript documentation

Tags: javascript, documentation

I wrote a javascript function that processes data and returns an object with a specific format.

```
function processData(itemToProcess){

    var information = itemToProcess.extractInformation();
    var returnedInfo = {
        "firstAttribute": information[0],
        "secondAttribute": information[1]
    };

    return returnedInfo;

}
```

I would like to specify for the @returns field the format of the returned object, but I don't know if there is a proper way to do it, or if I just have to format it on my own, like:

```
@returns : an object with the information formatted as:
    - firstAttribute: this attribute is the most important
    - secondAttribute: this attribute is the second most important
```

Is there a specific, proper way to document returned objects in Javascript, or is the coder's choice?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36759658/14104 is what I would do

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like a duplicate then. :)